# EC2 AMI instance store backup grub utility required

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, grub, amazon-ami, grub2

Working on backup of whole ec2 volume and image to upload to s3. Using RHEL7 and it internally uses Grub2 as bootloader. EC2 AMI tools requires grub legacy loader and I'm struck up in this loader. When i run ec2-bundle-vol, Stacktrace is as follows,

```
Partition type "mbr"
/usr/local/ec2/ec2-ami-tools-1.5.3/lib/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:196:in `block in verify_runtime': Required utility 'grub' not found in PATH - is it installed? (FatalError)
from /usr/local/ec2/ec2-ami-tools-1.5.3/lib/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:194:in `each'
```

Is there a way to make use of grub2 to run ec2 ami commands. pls guide !

Comment: What did Amazon tell you when you contacted them about this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I have reached them just now but no answer yet.. thought someone would have implemented bypassing the error..

Comment: That's silly. The first thing to do is report the problem to the developers so they can fix it!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Did Amazon get back to you?

Comment: I'm running into the same thing with Ubuntu 18.04 and up. Reported it at Packer but they (probably rightfully) won't have it https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/6974